# Apache2 doesn't load mod_cluster modules

Tags: jboss, apache2, debian, mod-cluster, opennebula

I'm working on a debian jessie machine instantiated inside open nebula with kvm. I have to install jboss eap and mod_cluster, so I need to install the apache2 service.

I followed the mod_cluster quick start guide and set the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file as follow:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule slotmem_module modules/mod_slotmem.so
LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so

ServerName master
Listen 10.0.0.6:6666
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.6:6666>
  <Directory />
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 10.0.0.
</Directory>

KeepAliveTimeout 60
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
ManagerBalancerName nebula
AdvertiseFrequency 5

<Location /mod_cluster_manager>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 10.0.0.
</Location>
```

When I run the command /etc/init.d/apache2 start it return error, systemctl status apache2.service -l shows me:

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-12-16 15:17:45 CET; 10min ago
Process: 844 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 16 15:17:45 debian apache2[844]: Starting web server: apache2 failed!
Dec 16 15:17:45 debian apache2[844]: The apache2 configtest failed. ... (warning).
Dec 16 15:17:45 debian apache2[844]: Output of config test was:
Dec 16 15:17:45 debian apache2[844]: apache2: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_proxy.so into server: /etc/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so: undefined symbol: ap_escape_html
Dec 16 15:17:45 debian apache2[844]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Dec 16 15:17:45 debian apache2[844]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Dec 16 15:17:45 debian systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 16 15:17:45 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Dec 16 15:17:45 debian systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state.
```

I can't understand what "undefined symbol: ap_escape_html" means and how I could resolve it.

Thanks in advance for help.

UPDATE 1: I tried to build httpd from source. I installed the pcre libraries also from source, but when I run PREFIX/bin/apachectl -k start it returns the following error:

```
/etc/httpd/bin/httpd: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you follow [this](https://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.1.0/html/Quick_Start_Guide.html)? And did you only copy the modules? If so, the jboss modules are compiled against a different httpd version than is shipped with Debian. You can either use the jboss httpd and disable the deb httpd, or compile the cluster module from source against the deb httpd.

Comment: @Kenney Yes, I followed that guide. I only copied the modules as the guide says. Initially I tried to use the httpd preconfigured installation downloaded from mod cluster, but when i try to run "/opt/jboss/httpd/apachectl start" it return the error: "httpd: not found". So I tried to install apache2 and configure it as the quick guide says copying the modules to /etc/apache2/modules/

Comment: I tried to dowload again mod cluster and reconfigure it, when I start apachectl start now it returns "/opt/jboss/httpd/sbin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /opt/jboss/httpd/lib/libapr-1.so.0: undefined symbol: dlopen"

Comment: Perhaps just stick to the stock Debian HTTPD (for automatic security updates) and [build mod_cluster from source](http://mod-cluster.jboss.org/#download). No quick-start, unfortunately.. Unless you can get the preconfigured installation to run - `httpd: not found` looks like a simple `$PATH` issue.

Comment: @Kenney I've just updated the question, I'm trying to install httpd from source but it returns error when i run apachectl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved libraries problems following this [guide](https://geekforum.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/install-apache-httpd-http-server/)