# Http doesn't load mod cluster modules

Tags: jboss, httpd.conf, nebula, mod-cluster

I'm trying to install mod_cluster on JBoss, after some problems with httpd solved in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314752/apache2-doesnt-load-mod-cluster-modules), now I'm stuck when I try to run "apachectl start", it returns the error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 128 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_slotmem.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_slotmem.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config
```

It seems like it can't run the mod cluster modules.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we were discussing the error message quite some time ago, 4th reference on Google for "undefined symbol: unixd_config" [See the discussion](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/236809?start=0&tstart=0&gateway=true).

The digest is that you cannot randomly mix mod_cluster 1.2.x and mod_cluster 1.3.x built either for httpd 2.2.x or httpd 2.4.x.

See http://modcluster.io/documentation/#configure-httpd where the loading of either `LoadModule cluster_slotmem_module modules/mod_cluster_slotmem.so` or `LoadModule slotmem_module modules/mod_slotmem.so` is described.

Last but not least, for having any meaningful response, always do include the version of your httpd, the version of mod_cluster modules, where did you get them or how you built them.